# Is SUSER_SNAME less secure then ORIGINAL_LOGIN?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Is there any reason with regard to security to use `ORIGINAL_LOGIN()` instead of `SUSER_SNAME()`? I know the difference between both.

My question concerns using `SUSER_SNAME()` in the `WHERE` clause:

```
select something, login from tb
where login=SUSER_SNAME()
```

Using `SUSER_SNAME()` seems less secure, however it allows for testing.

```
EXECUTE AS USER = 'test_user'
EXEC [dbo].[my_proc] 
REVERT
```

Isn't it a gate for a smart-fox-user to get into a data-chickencoop by changing `SUSER_SNAME()` in the same way I do for testing? Definitely `ORIGINAL_LOGIN()` would not allow that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) u1 can use `EXECUTE AS u2` only if he has `IMPERSONATE` rights for the `u2`

2) if you write your own permission check procedure (not server integrated) - it is your problem, how to avoid all possiblities(for this case may be `ORIGINAL_LOGIN` will be good).